# How to fix "Error resolving component in XSD file"?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm using an XSD which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--  XML schema -->

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="Mobiles">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Mobile" type="Mobile" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="Mobile">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Model" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="OS">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Android"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Origin" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Material" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Samsung" type="Samsung"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Samsung" mixed="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Wlan">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="802.11"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="CardSlot" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="RadioAvailability" type="xsd:boolean" default="true"/>
            <xsd:element name="BluetoothAvailability" type="xsd:boolean" default="false"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<p7:Mobiles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:p7="https://www.w3schools.com"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com input.xsd" >

    <Mobile>
        <Model>G975F</Model>
        <OS>Android</OS>
        <Origin>USA</Origin>
        <Material>Plastic</Material>
        <Samsung>
            <Wlan>802.11</Wlan>
            <CardSlot>MicroSD</CardSlot>
            <RadioAvailability>true</RadioAvailability>
            <BluetoothAvailability>true</BluetoothAvailability>
        </Samsung>
    </Mobile>
    <Mobile>
        <Model>G986</Model>
        <OS>Android</OS>
        <Origin>USA-Israel</Origin>
        <Material>Silicon-Plastic</Material>
        <Samsung>
            <Wlan>802.11</Wlan>
            <CardSlot>MicroSD</CardSlot>
            <RadioAvailability>true</RadioAvailability>
            <BluetoothAvailability>false</BluetoothAvailability>
        </Samsung>
    </Mobile>
    <Mobile>
        <Model>G770F</Model>
        <OS>Android</OS>
        <Origin>Israel</Origin>
        <Material>Silicon-Plastic</Material>
        <Samsung>
            <Wlan>802.11</Wlan>
            <CardSlot>MicroSD</CardSlot>
            <RadioAvailability>true</RadioAvailability>
            <BluetoothAvailability>false</BluetoothAvailability>
        </Samsung>
    </Mobile>
</p7:Mobiles>
```

Using this XSD I'm getting the issue:

> Error resolving component 'tns:Mobile'. It was detected that
> 'tns:Mobile' is in namespace `'https://www.w3schools.com'`, but
> components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema
> document. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of
> 'tns:Mobile' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace,
> then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to
> 'input_noTargetNamespace.xsd'.

To solve it I've checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43288137/8370915) with similar issue, but I don't have any namespace prefixes in `type="Samsung"` on the declaration of `Samsung`, so it looks like I'm missing something else.

Can someone explain the cause of issue in this case? Do I need to add something for `xsd:schema`? I can provide any other information if needed.

Comment: Rollback reason:  Question was already answered as posed.  Post a new question regarding your new variation that involves importation of a separate XSD.

Comment: [Second part of question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65650143/8370915)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsd:schema/@targetNamespace` of your XSD should match the namespace of the root element in your XML document.

Then, define a namespace prefix for the target namespace and use it to reference types in your XSD.

Below are your XSD and XML files corrected so that your XSD will validate your XML successfully:

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:w3s="https://www.w3schools.com"
            targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com">

  <xsd:element name="Mobiles">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Mobile" type="w3s:Mobile" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="Mobile">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Model" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="OS">
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Android"/>
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="Origin" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Material" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Samsung" type="w3s:Samsung"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="Samsung" mixed="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Wlan">
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="802.11"/>
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="CardSlot" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="RadioAvailability" type="xsd:boolean" default="true"/>
      <xsd:element name="BluetoothAvailability" type="xsd:boolean" default="false"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<p7:Mobiles xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:p7="https://www.w3schools.com"
            xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com input.xsd" >

  <Mobile>
    <Model>G975F</Model>
    <OS>Android</OS>
    <Origin>USA</Origin>
    <Material>Plastic</Material>
    <Samsung>
      <Wlan>802.11</Wlan>
      <CardSlot>MicroSD</CardSlot>
      <RadioAvailability>true</RadioAvailability>
      <BluetoothAvailability>true</BluetoothAvailability>
    </Samsung>
  </Mobile>
  <Mobile>
    <Model>G986</Model>
    <OS>Android</OS>
    <Origin>USA-Israel</Origin>
    <Material>Silicon-Plastic</Material>
    <Samsung>
      <Wlan>802.11</Wlan>
      <CardSlot>MicroSD</CardSlot>
      <RadioAvailability>true</RadioAvailability>
      <BluetoothAvailability>false</BluetoothAvailability>
    </Samsung>
  </Mobile>
  <Mobile>
    <Model>G770F</Model>
    <OS>Android</OS>
    <Origin>Israel</Origin>
    <Material>Silicon-Plastic</Material>
    <Samsung>
      <Wlan>802.11</Wlan>
      <CardSlot>MicroSD</CardSlot>
      <RadioAvailability>true</RadioAvailability>
      <BluetoothAvailability>false</BluetoothAvailability>
    </Samsung>
  </Mobile>
</p7:Mobiles>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated xsd and xml files with your corrections. But the problem is SonarQube wants one more xsd as `input_noTargetNamespace.xsd`, so I've added it as additional file in project, but I have the same issue: `Error resolving component 'w3s:Mobile'. It was detected that 'w3s:Mobile' is in namespace 'https://www.w3schools.com', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'w3s:Mobile' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag...`

Comment: I'll update now my question with two different xsd files which I have now

Comment: I answered your original question and fixed your XSD and XML as presented.   Please accept this answer and ask a new one regarding the new part about a second XSD.  Thanks.